# Convert links in blockquotes to plain text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xpath

So, I've been asking a lot of Xpath questions recently.
Sorry, but I've only just started using it, and I'm working on a kind of hard project.
You see, at the moment I'm parsing HTML like this (not a copy and paste, just an example):

```
<span id="no153434"></span>
<blockquote>Text here.<br/>More text.<br/>Some more text.</blockquote>
```

And I'm using

```
//span[starts-with(@id, 'no')]/following::*[1][name()='blockquote']//node()
```

To get the text inside.
It's working fine, although it's very frustrating. I need to manually check for 
 then manually combine the strings before and after the br, add a newline, and so on. But it stills works. Until there is a link in the text, that is. Then the code is like this:

```
<span id="no153434"></span>
<blockquote>Text here.<br/>Text.<br/><font class = "unkfunc"><a href="linkhere" class="link">linkhere</a></font></blockquote>
```

I have absolutely NO idea where to go from here, as the link is included as a completely seperate item (twice) in the array. Atleast with the br I knew where it had to be moved to. Really contemplating giving up in this project after all this effort.

Comment: Why not 1) retrieving the blockquote elements, 2) replacing inner br with "\n", 3) get all text nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to not use XPath for this kind of work.
Got it working 1,000,000x easier with Objective-C-HTML-Parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XPath to obtain text inside element: `//span[starts-with(@id, 'no')]/following::*[1][name()='blockquote']//text()`

So you receive following result:

1. Text here.
2. Text.
3. linkhere

Comment: But then I have no br's, so no linebreaks, so every line is seperate.

Comment: @Darcy, and what result do you want to receive?

Comment: Well, honestly I wish XPath could just clump everything from ONE BLOCKQUOTE into the SAME string, but it's a huge pain in the ass just to do that. Adding in links makes it almost impossible, because there's no way for me to tell if the link should be by itself, or on the end or start of another piece of text. Giving up this project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only text nodes and br:

```
 //span
  [starts-with(@id, 'no')]/
  following::*[1][name()='blockquote']
   //node()
   [ count(.|..//text()) = count(..//text())
     or 
     name()='br'
   ]
```

returns

```
Text here.
<br />
Text.
<br />
linkhere
```